# How to check if a point is inside a quad in perspective projection?

Tags: c++, opengl, transformation

I want to test if any given point in the world is on a quad/plane? The quad/plane can be translated/rotated/scaled by any values but it still should be able to detect if the given point is on it. I also need to get the location where the point should have been, if the quad was not applied any rotation/scale/translation.

For example, consider a quad at 0, 0, 0 with size 100x100, rotated at an angle of 45 degrees along z axis. If my mouse location in the world is at ( x, y, 0, ), I need to know if that point falls on that quad in its current transformation? If yes, then I need to know if no transformations were applied to the quad, where that point would have been on it? Any code sample would be of great help

Comment: I think this is an XY problem. I mean, you can of course *inverse*-transform your point and then use regular planar calculations, but if you are implementing something like picking (looks a lot like that), state it and the answers will be able to tune for that. Right now it's a bit too broad.

Comment: "consider a quad at 0, 0, 0 with size 100x100". That's underspecified.  Do you really mean quadrilateral, or did you mean rectangle (which is fully specified as width x height)? This makes a major difference for the answer.

Comment: @MSalters does it? Calculations for arbitrary quadrilaters only require forementioned tesselation (which should be done for rendering anyway).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Yes, a rectangle for instance is always convex. An arbitrary quadrilateral is not.

Comment: @MSalters I meant in terms of real rendering.

Comment: To clarify, you are wanting to cast a ray into the scene through your current mouse location and see if it hits a transformed rectangle, and if it does hit then you want the x,y intersection point on the rectangle? And are you working in 2D or 3D?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, I want to implement picking, but not through OpenGL way of changing the render mode.

Comment: @MSalters It is a rectangle initially, but after the transformations, it can or cannot be a rectangle.

Comment: @RichardNZ yes exactly, if it does hit, I want the x,y intersection point on the rectangle **in its original form i.e. without any transformations applied to it**. I am working in 3D. I have set up a perspective projection, but all my objects are just quads.

Comment: @RichardNZ To be exact, if it does hit, I want to convert that hit point to the local space coordinate of that object.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz *"I meant in terms of real rendering."* - Yet this question isn't about rendering in any way, it's about geometric calculations, where the difference between a general quadrilateral and a rectangle are of course important.

Answer (score 1):

A ray-casting approach is probably simplest:

1. Use `gluUnProject()` to get the world-space direction of the ray to cast into the scene. The ray's origin is the camera position.
2. Put this ray into object space by transforming it by the inverse of your rectangle's transform. Note that you need to transform both the ray's origin point and direction vector.
3. Compute the intersection point between this ray and the XY plane with a standard ray-plane intersection test.
4. Check that the intersection point's x and y values are within your rectangle's bounds, if they are then that's your desired result.

A math library such as [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net) will be very helpful if you aren't confident about some of the math involved here, it has corresponding functions such as `glm::unProject()` as well as functions to invert matrices and do all the other transformations you'd need.